# How to fix 503 error while using Jsoup to find data from Amazon

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, jsoup, http-status-code-503

I want to download the Amazon  books' pictures,i have a database of books;
i want to find these books' picture from amazon .so i use Jsoup to find it;
but when i run the program;its occured an error :

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=503, URL=http://www.amazon.cn/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=n%3A658390051%2Ck%3AA%20perfectly%20matched%20anisotropic%20absorber%20for%20use%20as%20an%20absorbing%20boundary%20condition
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:537)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:534)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:194)
    at util.ExtractService.extract(ExtractService.java:75)
```

how to fixed it? and is there other way to fixed this problem? python?

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 3):

I tried putting a user agent and it worked smooth.

```
Document document = Jsoup
                .connect("https://www.amazon.com/")
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.38 Safari/537.36")
                .get();
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Worked like a charme! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Error 503 implies a "service unavailable" error.

Try checking any connection issues:
1. Your internet connection
2. Do you need to use any proxy settings?
3. Do you have strict firewall settings that could be stopping your Jsoup connection?

Anything else under the sun that may cause the connection between your JVM and the website to fail.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP error 503 means 'Service Unavailable'.
There can be general reasons including Internet connection, related firewall, proxy settings from the machine, server being busy and server is under maintenance.

Even though those are the most possible reasons, there can be another scenario where the server has detected your Web scraping with Jsoup as a robot. Therefore, server can prevent Web scraping and simply implies it as an 503 error.